# Delete record from database with Cloud Spanner

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

In the Node.js example in the Cloud Spanner docs, I learned how to query, read, insert and update record from my Cloud Spanner database.
But I don't know how to 'delete' record.

Since the insertion and update method is just 'tablename.insert(...)' and'tablename.update(...)', I tried 'tablename.delete(...)' but it deleted the table itself. I want to delete record... Seems like DML statements doesn't work in query.

How can I delete record from database with Google's Cloud Spanner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `deleteRows`.

```
var keys = ['Id1', 'Id2', 'Id3'];
tablename.deleteRows(keys, function(err, apiResponse) {});
```

Link docs: Google Cloud Node ⇒ Cloud Spanner ⇒ Table ⇒ [deleteRows](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/spanner/0.1.0/spanner/table?method=deleteRows)

Answer (score 1):

As @Dan McGrath rightly pointed out, delete() actually drops the table

```
table.delete()
  .then(function(data) {
    const operation = data[0];
    return operation.promise();
  })
  .then(function() {
    // Table deleted successfully.
  });
```

To delete a row (record), use deleteRows()

```
table.deleteRows(keys)
  .then(function(data) {
    const apiResponse = data[0];
  });
```

Read more from https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/spanner/2.0.x/Table